How to resolve kmpnotifier-iosarm64 dependency in compose multiplatform for ios
After installing kmpnotifier 1.0.0 and trying to do Product -> Archive in xcode I get the error > Task :composeApp:linkReleaseFrameworkIosArm64 FAILED
error: The following dependencies exported in the releaseFramework binary are not specified as API-dependencies of a corresponding source set:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':composeApp:linkReleaseFrameworkIosArm64'.


Following dependencies exported in the releaseFramework binary are not specified as API-dependencies of a corresponding source set:

Files: [/Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/18821243bb7c3b1672eb35600772bf6c81bc1ee2/kmpnotifier.klib, /Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/97a3e2ee90b003ad2ff0f6e7778c2efc735ce39e/kmpnotifier-cinterop-FirebaseMessaging.klib]
Files: [/Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/18821243bb7c3b1672eb35600772bf6c81bc1ee2/kmpnotifier.klib, /Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/97a3e2ee90b003ad2ff0f6e7778c2efc735ce39e/kmpnotifier-cinterop-FirebaseMessaging.klib]
Files: [/Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/18821243bb7c3b1672eb35600772bf6c81bc1ee2/kmpnotifier.klib, /Users/romanmarinov/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/io.github.mirzemehdi/kmpnotifier-iosarm64/1.0.0/97a3e2ee90b003ad2ff0f6e7778c2efc735ce39e/kmpnotifier-cinterop-FirebaseMessaging.klib]
GRADLE 

plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrainsCompose)
    kotlin("plugin.serialization") version "2.0.0"

    alias(libs.plugins.google.services)
    alias(libs.plugins.firebase.crashlytics)
}

kotlin {
    androidTarget {
        @OptIn(ExperimentalKotlinGradlePluginApi::class)
        compilerOptions {
            jvmTarget.set(JvmTarget.JVM_11)
        }
    }

    listOf(
        iosX64(),
        iosArm64(),
        iosSimulatorArm64()
    ).forEach { iosTarget ->
        iosTarget.binaries.framework {
            baseName = "ComposeApp"
            isStatic = true
            //  export(project("io.github.mirzemehdi:kmpnotifier:1.0.0"))
           export(libs.kmpNotifier) // пока убрал
            freeCompilerArgs += listOf(
                "-Xbinary=bundleId=XXX.XXX.XXXXXXXXXXX",
                "-Xopt-in=kotlin.RequiresOptIn",
                "-Xinline-classes"
            )
        }
    }

    sourceSets {
        androidMain.dependencies {
            implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling.preview)
            implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
            //Firebase
            api(project.dependencies.platform(libs.firebase.bom))
            api(libs.firebase.analytics)
            api(libs.firebase.crashlytics)

            implementation(libs.firebase.messaging)

            api(libs.kmpNotifier)

            implementation(libs.androidx.startup.runtime)
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation("com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828")
        }
        commonMain.dependencies {
            implementation(compose.material3)
            implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
            implementation("org.jetbrains.androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.7.0-alpha07")
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.core)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging)
            implementation(libs.ktor.serialization.kotlinx.json)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
            implementation(libs.ktor.client.serialization)
            implementation(libs.kermit.v203) //Add latest version
            implementation(libs.koin.core)
            implementation(libs.koin.compose) // в этом проблема
            implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json:1.6.3")
            implementation("media.kamel:kamel-image:0.9.4")
            implementation("net.thauvin.erik.urlencoder:urlencoder-lib:1.5.0")
            implementation("io.github.kevinnzou:compose-webview-multiplatform:1.9.2")
            implementation("co.touchlab:kermit:2.0.2")
            implementation("co.touchlab:kermit-crashlytics:2.0.2")

            api(libs.kmpNotifier)
        }

        iosMain {
            dependencies {
                // implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:2.3.10")
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
         
                api(libs.kmpNotifier)
              //  api("io.github.mirzemehdi:kmpnotifier-iosarm64:0.6.0")

            }
            //sourceSets["main"].resources.srcDirs("src/commonMain/resources")


        }
        task("testClasses")
    }



LIB.VERSION.TOML

[versions]

agp = "8.2.0"
androidx-activityCompose = "1.8.2"
androidx-constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
compose = "1.7.0-alpha05" # было 1.7.0-beta01
compose-plugin = "1.6.10-rc01"
datastoreCore = "1.1.1"
kermitVersion = "2.0.2" #не повышать
koinAndroid = "3.5.6"
koinAndroidxCompose = "3.5.6"
koinCompose = "1.2.0-alpha3"
koinCore = "3.5.6"
serialization = "1.6.3"
androidx-lifecycle = "2.8.0-rc03"
androidx-startup-runtime = "1.1.1"
kotlin = "2.0.0-RC1"
ktorClientCore = "2.3.10"
core = "1.12.0"
lifecycleRuntimeKtx = "2.7.0" #было 2.7.0
composeBom = "2023.03.00" #было 2023.08.00
activityKtx = "1.9.0"
foundationAndroid = "1.6.7"
firebaseCrashlyticsBuildtools = "3.0.0"
androidx-data-store = "1.1.1" #at the time of this article
kmpNotifier = "1.0.0"
googleServices="4.4.0"
firebaseCrashlytics = "3.0.1"
firebaseBom="33.1.0"
firebasePerfKtx = "21.0.1"
firebase-messaging = "24.0.0"

[libraries]

androidx-datastore-core = { module = "androidx.datastore:datastore-core", version.ref = "datastoreCore" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-compose = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
kermit-v203 = { module = "co.touchlab:kermit", version.ref = "kermitVersion" }
koin-android = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-android", version.ref = "koinAndroid" }
koin-androidx-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-androidx-compose", version.ref = "koinAndroidxCompose" }
koin-compose = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-compose", version.ref = "koinCompose" }
koin-core = { module = "io.insert-koin:koin-core", version.ref = "koinCore" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "androidx-constraintlayout" }
androidx-activity-compose = { module = "androidx.activity:activity-compose", version.ref = "androidx-activityCompose" }
compose-ui-tooling = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling", version.ref = "compose" }
compose-ui-tooling-preview = { module = "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview", version.ref = "compose" }
ktor-client-cio = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-cio", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-client-content-negotiation = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-content-negotiation", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-client-core = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-core", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-client-darwin = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-darwin", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-client-logging = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-logging", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-client-serialization = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json = { module = "io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json", version.ref = "ktorClientCore" }
androidx-core = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core", version.ref = "core" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { group = "androidx.lifecycle", name = "lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleRuntimeKtx" }
androidx-compose-bom = { group = "androidx.compose", name = "compose-bom", version.ref = "composeBom" }
androidx-ui = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui" }
androidx-ui-graphics = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-graphics" }
androidx-ui-test-manifest = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-manifest" }
androidx-ui-test-junit4 = { group = "androidx.compose.ui", name = "ui-test-junit4" }
androidx-material3 = { group = "androidx.compose.material3", name = "material3" }
androidx-activity-ktx = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity-ktx", version.ref = "activityKtx" }
androidx-foundation-android = { group = "androidx.compose.foundation", name = "foundation-android", version.ref = "foundationAndroid" }
androidx-data-store-core = { module = "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-core", version.ref = "androidx-data-store" }
kotlinx-serialization-json = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-serialization-json", version.ref = "serialization"}
androidx-startup-runtime = { module = "androidx.startup:startup-runtime", version.ref = "androidx-startup-runtime" }

#Push Notification
kmpNotifier = { group = "io.github.mirzemehdi", name = "kmpnotifier", version.ref = "kmpNotifier" }
#Firebase
firebase-bom = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-bom", version.ref = "firebaseBom" }
firebase-analytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-analytics-ktx" }
firebase-crashlytics = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-crashlytics-ktx" }
firebase-perf-ktx = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-perf-ktx", version.ref = "firebasePerfKtx" }
firebase-messaging = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-messaging-ktx" ,version.ref="firebase-messaging"}

[plugins]
androidApplication = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
androidLibrary = { id = "com.android.library", version.ref = "agp" }
#jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
jetbrainsCompose = { id = "org.jetbrains.compose", version.ref = "compose-plugin" }
kotlinMultiplatform = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.multiplatform", version.ref = "kotlin" }
jetbrainsKotlinAndroid = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }

google-services = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "googleServices" }
firebase-crashlytics = { id = "com.google.firebase.crashlytics", version.ref = "firebaseCrashlytics" }





What worked for me is removing the 'project' term in:
listOf(
    iosX64(),
    iosArm64(),
    iosSimulatorArm64()
).forEach { iosTarget ->
    iosTarget.binaries.framework {
        export("io.github.mirzemehdi:kmpnotifier:1.3.0")
        baseName = "ComposeApp"
        isStatic = true
    }
}

